# Adding value accessors to function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I seem to be having some problems with the code below:

```
var chart = function(d) {
  var width = 0; // default width
  var height = 0; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
        console.log("The Input is " + d);
        console.log("chart height is " + my.height());
        console.log("chart width is " + my.width());
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return width;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return height;
  };

return my;
}
```

When I set `var myvar = chart().width(20);` then call `myvar.width()` later it still outputs 0, instead of 20 like I would expect and throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined`. I feel like I'm fairly close to a solution but I can't quite figure out how to fix this problem.

I'm new to using get/set methods so anything to get me on the right path would be much appreciated!

I used [Mike Bostocks](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/) Towards Reusable Charts as a basis.

EDIT UPDATE: I would like the input width and height to be accessible within the my() function.

Comment: Your `chart` function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, and I think I was a bit vague in my question.

```
 var chart = function(d) {
    var width = 0; // default width
    var height = 0; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
    console.log(d);
    console.log("width " + width + " height " + height);
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return my;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return my;
  };

  return my;
}
```

Then in the main code you write `chart("Test")()` to invoke the inner function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the function my in return, you can return the function my.

This should work

```
var chart = function(d) {
  var width = 0; // default width
  var height = 0; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
        console.log("The Input is " + d);
        console.log("chart height is " + my.height());
        console.log("chart width is " + my.width());
  }

  my.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return width;
  };

  my.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return height;
  };

return my;
}
```

and then

`var myvar = chart();
myvar.width(20);
myvar.width();`

this will give you 20

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code to this. I would like the my() function to generate a graph based in the input height and width. The problem that I seem to have is that the my() function does not run at the end of this.

Answer (score 0):

do you intend to do something like this ?

```
function chart(d) {
  var width = 0; // default width
  var height = 0; // default height

  function my() {
    // generate chart here, using `width` and `height`
        console.log("The Input is " + d);
        console.log("chart height is " + this.height());
        console.log("chart width is " + this.width());
  }

  my.prototype.width = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = value;
    return this;
  };

  my.prototype.height = function(value) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = value;
    return this;
  };

return new my();
}

var x = new chart().width(5).height(7); // sets width to 5 and height to 7
x.width() // returns 5
x.height() // returns 7
```

Comment: You probably don't want to wrap the constructor and prototypes inside a `chart` function at all. That will re-create them on every call.